# imageURL correct but when trying to run in IIS Express there is a broken link for the image

Tags: image, visual-studio-2017, imageurl

I am doing a training exercise to get a simple png file to show up on an ASP page.  I am using the following relative link URL:

```
images/pencil.png
```

When I set the image url in the design view, the pencil appears, so it appears to be the right path:

[image: pencil.png image]

However whenever I try and set the image after a button click with this code:

```
resultLabel.Text = "You selected pencil";
imageResult.ImageUrl ="images/pencil.png";
```

When I run IIS Express, I just get a broken link.  Any advice here?  I tried turning on the static content in the windows features but had no luck.  I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Getting the following error when I look in the Console in Microsoft Edge:
[image: MS Error for ASP]

Comment: Try adding ~/ before images in the path

Comment: @RajSappidi Tried that but it didn't help

Comment: @Vaslo Do you have an image folder at the root of your application containing the pencil.png file?

Comment: Yes-the folder is in the same level as the default.aspx, and assume I need to go one deeper to approach the files.  I tried to put the files alone in the outer folder with no folder and still no picture. Again though, in design view it is finding the picture and posting it, so I think the path is right.  Something wrong with IIS is my belief.